# JPA and Hibernate One To One Shared Primary Key Uni-directional Mapping in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I want to have one-to-one uni-directional mapping with 2 child entities using shared primary key. Below are model classes

```
public class Template implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "templatekey")
    Integer templateKey;

    @Column(name = "templateid", unique = true)
    String templateId;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "templatekey", referencedColumnName = "templatekey")
    InstantOfferNoEsp instantOfferNoEsp;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "templatekey", referencedColumnName = "templatekey")
    Mobile mobile;

     //constructor , setter and getters

}

Child 1 :

public class Mobile implements Serializable {
   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "templatekey")
    Integer templateKey;
    
    String mobileNewUrl;


    //constructor , setter and getters

}

Child 2:

public class InstantOfferNoEsp {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "templatekey")
    Integer templateKey;

    String offerCodeType;

    String headerUrl;
 
    //constructor , setter and getters
}
```

I want templateKey as PK in all tables. and I am calling `templateRepository.save(template);` to save all entities at once but its not working and getting `ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()` error.

Any suggestions would be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: Could you specify what actually generation strategy are you going to use for the `templateKey` - `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`?

Comment: I want to use `strategy = GenerationType.AUTO` in Parent (Template)... and that should be shared among children's

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-auto). It's quite difficult to guess how it will be  interpreted. It will depends on hibernate version/hibernate configuration (do you use hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings), database what you use

Comment: I'm using mysql database and its using hibernate_sequence for getting Id

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do what you want with bidirectional `@OneToOne` like below:

```java
@Entity
public class Mobile {

    @Id
    Integer templateKey;
    
    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "templatekey")
    Template template;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class InstantOfferNoEsp {

    @Id
    Integer templateKey;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "templatekey")
    Template template;
 
    // ...
}


@Entity
public class Template {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "templatekey")
    Integer templateKey;

    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "template", optional = false)
    InstantOfferNoEsp instantOfferNoEsp;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "template", optional = false)
    Mobile mobile;

    // ...

    public void setMobile(Mobile mobile)
    {
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.mobile.setTemplate(this);
    }

    public void setInstantOfferNoEsp(InstantOfferNoEsp instantOfferNoEsp)
    {
        this.instantOfferNoEsp = instantOfferNoEsp;
        this.instantOfferNoEsp.setTemplate(this);
    }
}
```

and an example of saving:

```java
Mobile mobile = new Mobile();
mobile.setMobileNewUrl("MOB1");

InstantOfferNoEsp instant = new InstantOfferNoEsp();
instant.setOfferCodeType("INST_OFF1");
      
Template template = new Template();
template.setTemplateId("TMP1");
template.setInstantOffer(instant);
template.setMobile(mobile);
entityManager.persist(template);
```

P.S. The following mapping works too, but only if we set `Template.templateKey` manually.

```java
@Entity
public class Template
{
   @Id
   // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "templatekey")
   Integer templateKey;

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "templatekey", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   InstantOfferNoEsp instantOfferNoEsp;

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "templatekey", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   Mobile mobile;
 
   // ...
}
```

and an example of saving:

```java
Mobile mobile = new Mobile();
mobile.setMobileNewUrl("MOB1");

InstantOfferNoEsp instant = new InstantOfferNoEsp();
instant.setOfferCodeType("INST_OFF1");
      
Template template = new Template();
template.setTemplateKey(20);
template.setTemplateId("TMP1");
template.setInstantOffer(instant);
template.setMobile(mobile);
entityManager.persist(template);
```

Also I would suggest your explicitly specify what generation strategy you want to use (do not use `GenerationType.AUTO`) and use corresponding object wrapper classes instead of primitive types for `@Id` fields.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.xxx.xxx.model.Mobile while calling templateRepository.save(template). `do we need to manually persist parent and then pass id of parent to childrens

Comment: Try to use mapping from the updated answer

Comment: Try to use mapping from the updated answer if bidirectional @OneToOne is acceptable for you.

Comment: Thanks Stern... we agreed to go with bi-directional and your solution is working.